# Do I need to memset a C struct in Swift?

Tags: c, swift, struct, memset

AFAIK, In swift, calling the default initialiser of classes/structs will initialise everything to `0` , `nil`.
In C (socket programming for example) sometimes memset is used to set everything to 0 before using the struct. Do I need to use memset in swift too or is fine the way I wrote it?

(BTW, In this case `memset` is used because `hints` should be set to 0 except below 2 parameters. Non 0 (garbage, etc) will have side effects on `res` when calling `getaddrinfo`.

### C:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int status;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

status = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &res);
```

### Swift:

```
var res = UnsafeMutablePointer<addrinfo>()
var hints = addrinfo()
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM

let status = getaddrinfo(nil, MYPORT, &hints, &res)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Xcode 6.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW26):

> Imported C structs now have a default initializer in Swift that
> initializes all of the struct's fields to zero.

which means that

```
var hints = addrinfo()
```

initializes all fields of `struct addrinfo` to zero and there is no need to call `memset()`.

Comment: I created `xmlSAXHandler` struct of `libxml` (imported through .modulemap) and printed memory bytes using [`bytes<T>` method](https://academy.realm.io/posts/goto-mike-ash-exploring-swift-memory-layout/) but not all bytes are 0.

Comment: Can this be due to `memory padding`?

Comment: I need to wipe out a string from memory in swift? any help?