# Which types initialise with default zero value when using a constructor in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, initialization

Looking through a Swift MIDI library, I found a variable initialised like so:

```
var client = MIDIClientRef()
```

I only thought this was weird after realising that MIDIClientRef isn't a function, it's a typealias for a `UInt32`, so wondered why the constructor pattern is used.

So a few simple questions:

- Is it common to initialise a variable like this: `var myVar = Int()`?
- Which types initialise with a default zero value when initialised with a constructor like this?
- *How* does it initialise with a zero value if no argument is passed in?

Looking at the `public init()` function in `Swift.Math.Integers` the comments state that it "Creates a new value equal to zero." But I couldn't find what actually creates this default value in the following code.

Comment: a) I don’t know how common it is, I prefer `.zero` or a literal value, b) I would assume all numeric types c) why not, what other value would be more appropriate as a default value than zero?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JoakimDanielson. Perhaps my "Why" question should instead be "How" (see the answers...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UInt32` conforms to the [`BinaryInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger) protocol and that requires an `init()` method which “Creates a new value equal to zero.”

There is also a default implementation which can be found in [`Integers.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift#L1240):

```
extension BinaryInteger {
  /// Creates a new value equal to zero.
  @_transparent
  public init() {
    self = 0
  }

  // ...
}
```

Other types have explicit no-argument init methods, like [all floating point types](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L79):

```
  @_transparent
  public init() {
    let zero: Int64 = 0
    self._value = Builtin.sitofp_Int64_FPIEEE${bits}(zero._value)
  }
```

Examples:

```
let d = Double()
let f = Float()
let c = CGFloat()
```

Finally, all types which are imported from C have a default initializer in Swift that initializes all of the struct's fields to zero, as mentioned in the [Xcode 6 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html). Example (from [Do I need to memset a C struct in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30971278/1187415)):

```
let hints = addrinfo()
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise there was anything "below" types like UInt32 for them to conform to. X-Code reference is particularly interesting.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer what is essentially a noob/curiosity question in such detail.

Answer (score 1):

It is an initializer on BinaryInteger protocol. It is declared as

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    /// Creates a new value equal to zero.
    @_transparent
    public init() {
        self = 0
    } 

    // ...
}
```

You can check its implementation at [Integers](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/971537c04397c019794cb69d6352f9da8b047cfe/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift#L1240)

Comment: Sorry about the duplication, I had already started collecting the information :)